# Is there an alternative to CleanSweep?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s an extremely vigilant uninstaller application?](https://superuser.com/questions/58799/whats-an-extremely-vigilant-uninstaller-application)

There was a product called CleanSweep, a very mature uninstaller. Are there any such tools available now that can track the installation as the Setup starts?

Comment: It's a great question but it will likely be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/58799/whats-an-extremely-vigilant-uninstaller-application

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

> Revo Uninstaller helps you to
>   uninstall software and remove unwanted
>   programs installed on your computer
>   even if you have problems uninstalling
>   and cannot uninstall them from
>   "Windows Add or Remove Programs"
>   control panel applet.
>
> Revo Uninstaller analyzes an
>   application's data before uninstall
>   and scans after you uninstall an
>   application. After the program's
>   regular uninstaller runs, you can
>   remove additional unnecessary files,
>   folders and registry keys that are
>   usually left over on your computer.
>   Even if you have a broken
>   installation, Revo Uninstaller scans
>   for an application's data on your hard
>   disk drives and in the Windows
>   registry and shows all found files,
>   folders and registry keys so you can
>   delete them.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia (don't shoot the messenger...):

> **Third-party uninstallers today**
>
> Nowadays, pure third-party
> uninstallers (uninstallers that only
> contain basic components -- that is
> the watcher, logger, uninstaller, and
> probably the analyzer) generally are
> unpopular and are not needed anymore,
> because:
>
> Most software programs come with their
> own uninstallers (which are generally
> better and more accurate), Most
> uninstallers are not entirely accurate
> (most of them are known to leave
> leftovers, which should be deleted by
> uninstallers), There are many better
> and safer tools that can be used to
> replace uninstallers, Because of this,
> to make uninstallers more
> merchantable, most (if not all) of
> today's uninstallers contain other
> related tools (such as a cache
> cleaner, a junk file cleaner, etc.)
>
> Why the third-party uninstallers are
> still used today:
>
> More complex installed programs make
> system changes that the authors
> forget, ignore or are not aware. They
> often integrate third-party components
> with no thought of their
> uninstallation. The competition to
> release new software versions with
> additional features leave the
> uninstallation with a very small
> amount of attention and testing. The
> accuracy of the integrated
> uninstallers commonly leave much to be
> desired. The uninstallers that don't
> contain a logger module are
> aggressively promoted on the market
> claiming that completely uninstall
> programs (a task that is impossible
> and even dangerous without monitoring
> installation) Many programs are
> bundled with all kind of add-ons,
> spyware or not, that are intentionally
> left on the user's computer after
> uninstallation of the main program. At
> this time-- when adware, spyware,
> keyloggers, trojans and other Internet
> threats appear every day--
> installation of a software product
> from an unknown source is a great
> risk. When things go wrong with a
> newly installed program, an
> uninstaller with a logger module can
> prove invaluable.

Besides the Wikipedia info, I do recall problems with CleanSweep when you altered / added / deleted files while installing software. Furthermore, did CleanSweep check whether files where used by multiple applications (like shared dll's)?

Answer (score 0):

[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) is very good at finding the detritus left over from incomplete uninstalls.